# Compiling Linux kernel - hello world

Tags: linux, kernel

I am trying to compile the Linux kernel: 
http://tldp.org/LDP/lkmpg/2.6/html/lkmpg.html

I have a simple hello world program hello-1.cpp

```
#include <linux/module.h>
#include <linux/kernel.h>

int init_module(void)
{
    return 0;
}

void cleanup_module(void)
{
}
```

But I am trying to build it using the Makefile:

```
obj-m += hello-1.o

all:
make -C /lib/modules/$(shell uname -r)/build M=$(PWD) modules

clean:
make -C /lib/modules/$(shell uname -r)/build M=$(PWD) clean
```

I get a couple of errors.

```
make -C /home/pacman/linux-2.6.34.11/2.6.35.6-45.fc14.i686/build M=/home/pacman/p1 modules
make: *** /home/pacman/linux-2.6.34.11/2.6.35.6-45.fc14.i686/build: No such file or directory.  Stop.
```

make: *** [all] Error 2

Am I forgetting to define something?

Comment: In my case the example compiled correctly. In your case the build directory that you are passing as an argument to make is not being found. Try to follow the tutorial in this [website](http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/compiling-linux-kernel-module.html) to see if it solves your problem or as an alternative you can search for the build dir of your kernel version and pass it as an argument of make.

Comment: In the /home/pacman/linux-2.6.34.11 directory am I expected to see a build directory or file ? I have a file Kbuild.

Comment: I'm using Ubuntu as a distro. You are using FC. So, I found this [post](http://www.linuxforums.org/forum/kernel/95767-problem-compiling-kernel-module-fedora-core-6-a.html) where they explain that you need to have the kernel-devel package that matches your kernel.

Comment: There is some mismatch, your Makefile command line starts `make -C /lib/modules/...` but the command line shows `make -C /home/pacman/...`.

Comment: Have you solved your problem?

Answer (score 1):

Rename hello-1.**cpp** to hello-1.**c** (modules must be written in C) and add the lines:

```
module_init(init_module);
module_exit(cleanup_module);
```